# Are you aware of the proposed "Audio Recording and Production" site? What do you think?

Tags: opinion, forum, collaboration

I appreciate the need to distinguish between recording and production as a recording or mixing engineer, for example, and the broader field of sound design.

What do you think?

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4?phase=definition

**The following should have been labeled an aside. I should have made it clearer that I see the proposal as non-competitive with this site.**

(I have been a little disappointed over the course of StackExchange's existence that several websites are redundant and hurt each other's value.)

Comment: It looks to me like that site is a beginner's arena for the home-studio musician who just wants a simple magic-bullet answer on how to set up a record rig for his acoustic guitar and SM57 mic. Social Sound Design goes intensely deeper than that. I've noticed that each and every consistent member of SSD has technical knowledge and know-how beyond belief and is truly an advanced community for advanced question and advice - and without the spam and nonsense as is prevalent on other well-known message-board systems on the subject. SSD will most likely never be matched in that regard, lets keep it.

Comment: You can post that as an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, not exactly sure I understand you're question…are you asking if that site needs to exist independently of this site (SSD)? Or if it is redundant, and there should be only one site where folks can address many topics?

Personally, from a really quick scan through the postings and replies/comments, it comes across as harsh and heavy-handed with a bunch of irrelevant and annoying questions. (Maybe it's good that that site *does* exist, so they don't flood us instead!)

Comment: It does look and sound pretty flat for now, probably because there is not a big community behind it and the questions are obvious non-subtle fakes that are supposed to show what to ask and not to ask. It does not look very appealing, maybe it'll get there... It's the community's responsibility to make it a place worthwhile. This is what makes SSD what it is, the community, it's not just Andrew (Spitz) and a bunch of random guys with beginners questions.

Comment: Huge +1! You said it right there.

Comment: Exactly, all we need is a know-it-all troll over here telling us how we're idiots and he's gods gift to post-production sound.

Answer (score 6):

Even though there's a certain amount of related topics, that site is more for musicians, studio engineering and music production? That's not what this site is for.

I'd rather that area was missing from here. Specialism is no bad thing.

Comment: Ditto. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the site is exactly unnecessary, but it certainly does have a different feel than this site.